# perl DBI module installation erroring out

Tags: perl, installation

perl DBI module installation is erroring out.

Installed perl 5.32.1 in non standard location, using -Dinstallprefix  option

```
./Configure -Dinstallprefix=/test/user/home/perl -des
make
make test
make install

/test/user/home/perl/bin/perl -version
This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for x86_64-linux
```

Set PERL5LIB env variable

```
export PERL5LIB="/test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1:/test/user/home/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1:/test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux"

which perl
/test/user/home/perl/bin/perl
```

Downloaded DBI-1.643 archive, after extraction execution of Makefile.PL is failing

```
perl Makefile.PL

Warning: PERL_LIB (/perl/lib/5.32.1) seems not to be a perl library directory
        (strict.pm not found) at /test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm line 1934.
Have /test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux
Want /perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux
Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.
Perl thinks: [x86_64-linux]
Config says: [x86_64-linux]
This may or may not cause problems. Please check your installation of perl
if you have problems building this extension.
Can't stat /perl/lib/5.32.1: No such file or directory
 at Makefile.PL line 280.
Can't stat /perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux: No such file or directory
 at Makefile.PL line 280.
Failed to opendir '/perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux/CORE' to find header files: No such file or directory at /test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm line 3048.
```

Found non existing paths are referred from @INC

```
perl -e "print \"@INC\""

/test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1 /test/user/home/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1 /test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux
/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1/x86_64-linux /perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1 /perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux /perl/lib/5.32.1
```

Can someone guide me where from @INC getting these non existing paths

```
/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1/x86_64-linux /perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1 /perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux /perl/lib/5.32.1
```

are there any way to restrict @INC to append non existing paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want just `-Dprefix=/...`. There are other things that need to end up in the right place too. You shouldn't need to set `PERL5LIB` though because perl should be using your prefix as its default `@INC`. What does your `perl -V` show?

There is an `installprefix`, but it's aimed at compiling on one machine and installing on another. However, the [INSTALL](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/INSTALL) docs also recommend against using that. Is that what you are trying to do?

As for the other directories, the [INSTALL](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/INSTALL) docs describe the various directories that show up in `@INC`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @brian for pointing me in right direction.

Following was the root cause behind @INC contains non existing directories.

Last time during perl installation at least one time I ran following command

```
./Configure -des -Dprefix=/perl

Use relocatable @INC? [n]
Pathname where the private library files will reside? (~name ok)
[/perl/lib/5.32.1]
Where do you want to put the public architecture-dependent libraries? (~name ok)
[/perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux]
Pathname for the site-specific library files? (~name ok)
[/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1]
Pathname for the site-specific architecture-dependent library files? (~name ok)
[/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1/x86_64-linux]
```

then executed make command. Later on make test failed for other error.

Then without running  make distclean command, I re ran Configure with
-Dinstallprefix option

```
./Configure -Dinstallprefix=/test/user/home/perl -des
```

This populate @INC as follows

```
/test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1 /test/user/home/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1 /test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux
/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1/x86_64-linux /perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1 /perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux /perl/lib/5.32.1
```

To fix this issue executed following steps,

```
make distclean  

./Configure -des -Dprefix=/test/user/home/perl -Dusethreads
```

now @INC is populated correct

```
@INC:
    /test/user/home/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /test/user/home/perl/lib/site_perl/5.32.1
    /test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /test/user/home/perl/lib/5.32.1
```

Now DBI installation ran successfully.